# How to import all classes in one file and use them from there typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

For example, I have a class **`A.ts`**

```
export class A(){
    public constructor() {}
    public method() : string {
         return "hello from A";
    }
}
```

and class **`B.ts`**

```
export class B(){
    public constructor() {}

    public method() : string {
         return "hello from B";
    }

    public static methodStatic() : string {
        return "hello from static B";
    }
}
```

then I want to import all of them in ONE file Headers.ts

```
imports {A} from    "../A_path";
imports * as b from "../B_path";

//Or just to export it? Make it public.
export * from "../A_path";
export * from "../B_path";
```

Headers.ts will contain only `imports/exports`, no class implementation or any other code.
And then my problem: I want to use **`A`** and **`B`** classes in app.ts calling them over **`Headers.ts`** file.

```
import * as headers from './HEADERS_path';
headers.A.method();
headers.B.method();
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK I found the solution: 
in the file **Headers.ts** I need only to export classes:

```
export {A} from "../A_path";
export {B} from "../B_path";
```

and then to use class **B**, I need to import  **Headers.ts** in **app.ts** file:

```
import * as headers from './HEADERS_path';
```

then I gonna make an instance of **B** class and call it's methods easily:

```
let bInstance : headers.B = new headers.B();
//concrete method
bInstance.method();
//output will be what is expected: *"hello from B"*

//static method
headers.B.methodStatic();
//output will be what is expected: *"hello from static B"*
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to export all classes in `Headers.ts`

```
export {A} from "../A_path";
export {B} from "../B_path";
```

If you have multiple classes in `A_path` for example you can do:

`export * from "../A_path";`

Note that you can't use `export * from` with `default` exports.

You can read more about import/export on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Description).